# How do I provide a relative path to Buffer.read?

Tags: supercollider

So I want to load a sound file into a buffer using a relative path. (I keep my stuff under version control and don't want to make any assumptions about where someone might clone the repo on their file system.)

So, I initially assumed that if I provided a path that looked relative then SC would interpret it as being relative to the location of the file being executed:

```
Buffer.read(s, "Samples/HiHats1.hihat2.wav");
```

But SC couldn't find the file. So I looked up `asAbsolutePath` and tried that:

```
Buffer.read(s, "Samples/HiHats1.hihat2.wav".asAbsolutePath);
```

This doesn't work either because SC can't work out the absolute path from my relative one.

```
"Samples/HiHats1.hihat2.wav".asAbsolutePath
```

...actually returns a nonexistent location on my filesystem. Hurrah!

Can anyone make any suggestion as to how I might achieve this troublesome task?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

SuperCollider handles relative paths just fine - just like a lot of software, it resolves them relative to the **current working directory**. Usually this is relative to the executable, not the script file, hence the confusion.

What's the current working directory in your case? You can find out by running

```
     File.getcwd
```

(This is what `.asAbsolutePath` uses.) The cwd depends on your OS - on some platforms it's not a particularly handy default. You can't rely on it being anything in particular.

In your case, if you want the path to be resolved relative to the location of **your script or class**, then you need to do that yourself. For example:

```
     // Use the path of whatever file is currently executing:
     var samplePath = thisProcess.nowExecutingPath.dirname +/+ "Samples/HiHats1.hihat2.wav";

     // Use the path of the class file for the class you're coding
     var samplePath = this.class.filenameSymbol.asString.dirname +/+ "Samples/HiHats1.hihat2.wav";
```

Comment: Once again, thanks for both the solution and the explanation.

Comment: One caveat to this: `thisProcess.nowExecutingPath` only works on the IDE and the `scel` environments interactively. All others (e.g. scvim) return `nil`.

Comment: To get around the issue I mentioned above, there is the `-d` flag when calling `sclang`, which specifies the runtime directory. If you run `sclang -d $(pwd)` in the same directory as your scripts/sounds, then you'll be able to have a relatively portable project.